# Tensorflow Performance Measurement Not Working on Android

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am following the guideline from https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/measurement#performance_benchmarks_for_well_known_models

I am trying to perform the benchmark on a pixel 2.

I have downloaded android_arm benchmark app that supports tf operation.

and is using the Mobilenet_1.0_224(float) provided from the same site.

I have run the following commands:

```
adb install -r -d -g './android_arm_benchmark_model_plus_flex.apk'
adb push mobilenet_v1_1.0_224.tflite /data/local/tmp
```

Afterwards, I ran

```
adb shell am start -S   -n org.tensorflow.lite.benchmark/.BenchmarkModelActivity --es args '"--graph=/data/local/tmp/mobilenet_v1_1.0_224.tflite --num_threads=4"'
```

which returns

```
Stopping: org.tensorflow.lite.benchmark
Starting: Intent { cmp=org.tensorflow.lite.benchmark/.BenchmarkModelActivity (has extras) }
```

Now when I try to get view inference results

```
adb logcat | grep "Average inference"
```

My terminal just hangs (Nothing happens)

What did I do wrong in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that there was no "Average Inference" in the logs.

```
adb logcat | grep "tflite"
```

Worked for me.